# Samsung Galaxy S2 battery gets hot

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, charging, battery-life

My Galaxy S2 is less than a year old. The battery sucks! I have to charge it more than once a day.

Tonight, while on the charger, the battery life is actually going down. It's also way too hot to touch. Any inputs?

Comment: What did you do with it while it was on the charger? Download HD video from Youtube via 3G while watching it with display brightness set to 100%, while uploading a life-stream captured via the integrated cam? That's the best combination I know to make you need wearing gloves if you want to touch it. In other words: If you run something with a lot of "hunger" while charging, it might be normal for the battery to get hot. And there are components consuming it faster than it charges (e.g. video recording).

Comment: take the battery out and put it back in, do you have any shady, recently installed app/service running in the background that can be the cause of this? have you tried calibrating the battery?